# AWS EMR 'Unable to find host' PuTTY

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-emr, putty

so I have made an EMR cluster, and have edited the master security group inbound rules so that it accepts SSH from 'My IP'. I was following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r-ig8zpP3EM). The only problem is the following: when I try to SSH into the instance using PuTTY, I get the following error:

```
Unable to open connection to ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal, Host does not exist.
```

In my PuTTY config, I pasted in my .ppk key and am using the hadoop@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal as the Host Name. Not sure why this isn't working. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Your DNS Name seems incorrect -- it should not mention `.internal`. Take a look in the console and try to find the **Master public DNS** that ends with `.com`.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Master public DNS is in the following form: ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce your situation, I did the following:

- Launched an Amazon EMR 2-node cluster using "Quick Options", my own keypair and otherwise default options
- Edited the `EMR-Master` security group to allow access from my IP address on port 22
- Copied the **Master public DNS** shown the EMR console:

[image: Amazon EMR settings]

- Connected to the Master node via SSH:

```
ssh -i key.pem hadoop@ec2-13-54-245-33.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

It successfully logged in.

Your issue seems to be that the Master public DNS is being returned as an 'internal' DNS name rather than a 'public' name. Examples can be found on [Launching and Running an Amazon EMR Cluster inside a VPC | AWS Big Data Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/launching-and-running-an-amazon-emr-cluster-inside-a-vpc/).

It is possible that your VPC has been configured without public access, but I could not see where this might have been configured.